# pythonw.exe do not work with canopy

Tags: python, python-2.7, enthought, canopy

I installed Enthought Canopy express 64-bit on Windows 7 professional 64-bit.

Then I got some .py and .pyw files. At first they are linked to Canopy so I cannot run .pyw files without console.

So I changed to open .pyw with pythonw.exe, but no results came out. I checked with IDLE.exe and if I open the file in IDLE and run it, it works. How can I set .pyw files to run without console?

Answer (score 0):

Which pythonw.exe did you associate with your .pyw files?

They should be associated with the pythonw in your Canopy User Python, as described here:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-User-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-

This would normally be here:
 C:\Users\YOUR-USER-ID\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts\pythonw.exe

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I associate with. Unfortunately it does not work anyway. Thanks.